# Move to RelativeLayout center

Tags: android

I have layout below that consist of two elements. `verInfo` is located in top left conner and it is ok. `editTextNumber` should be in the center of whole layout. I was expecting `android:layout_gravity` will do the trick, but I still have both elements located on each other.

How to solve the problem?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/info_in_my"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/verInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Version 5"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` does the trick